# Send single CheckBox value in array to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am having multiple checkboxes on form and I am going to submit the form.

```
  $.fn.serializeObject = function () {
        'use strict';
        debugger;
        var result = {};
        var extend = function (i, element) {
            var node = result[element.name];
            // If node with same name exists already, need to convert it to an array as it
            // is a multi-value field (i.e., checkboxes)
            if ('undefined' !== typeof node && node !== null) {
                if ($.isArray(node)) {
                    node.push(element.value);
                } else {
                    result[element.name] = [node, element.value];
                }
            } else {
                result[element.name] = element.value;
            }
        };
        $.each(this.serializeArray(), extend);
        return result;
    };
```

and code is like

```
  var that = $(this);
  var temp = $(JSON.stringify());
  form_data = that.serializeObject(temp);
  form_data = JSON.stringify(form_data);
```

everything works fine but if I single select a checkbox then the value is like 
        `"checkboxName":"value1"`
  and if I select  multiple  values of checkboc then the vale is like 
        `"checkboxName":["value1","value2","value3"]`

I want that a single value should also be selected in array format that is 
        `"checkboxName":["value1"]`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Checkboxes are for multiple value selections. Maybe you are searching for radio buttons. What is the purpose to send only one value of a checkbox group with multiple selected values?

Comment: Ok, I see your edition. Forget that i said in first comment

Answer (score 0):

If you try:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function () {
    'use strict';
    debugger;
    var result = {};
    var extend = function (i, element) {
        var node = result[element.name];
        // If node with same name exists already, need to convert it to an array as it
        // is a multi-value field (i.e., checkboxes)
        if ('undefined' !== typeof node && node !== null) {
            if ($.isArray(node)) {
                node.push(element.value);
            } else {
                result[element.name] = [node, element.value];
            }
        } else {
            //Here you are the checkbox condition
            if(element.tagName == "INPUT" && element.getAttribute("type") == "checkbox") {
                  result [element.name] = [element.value];
            } else {
                  result[element.name] = element.value;
            }
        }
    };
    $.each(this.serializeArray(), extend);
    return result;
};
```